# Incompatibility between MySQL and MariaDB - Subquery in FROM clause.

Tags: mysql, mariadb

MariaDB claims to be a drop-in replacement for MySQL, but [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html) states that this feature is available since version 5.7.7:

> Before MySQL 5.7.7, the SELECT statement cannot contain a subquery in
>   the FROM clause.

[MariaDB knowledge base](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/create-view/) says this is not allowed:

> The SELECT statement cannot contain a subquery in the FROM clause.

However, this is not listed in [MariaDB's compatibility page](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/#incompatibilities-between-mariadb-101-and-mysql-57).

I've made some tests and it seems like there's no support for this kind of query in MariaDB, but the conflicting information in MariaDB docs made me confused. So, which one of the pages from MariaDB is right? Is this feature really not supported (yet)?

Comment: file a bug report

Comment: MYSQL & MariaDB may have started out as the same thing, but as time goes by they are going to diverge more and more

Comment: `VIEWs` have been halfheartedly implemented.  At some point Oracle or MariaDB will take them seriously.  At that point, there will be more divergence.  My opinion:  Avoid `VIEWs`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you conducted the tests yourself on the latest version of MariaDB (mysql v5.7.7 was released in April 2015, so it is not new, nevertheless you should test the latest MariaDB) and the result was that MariaDB instance did not support subqueries in the from clause of views, then this what it is.

Yes, it should probably highlighted in the differences section. You may consider raising a bug report around the documentation being incorrect. Since the MariaDB manual on views is accurate, this is a documentation issue only. Just make sure that you did test the latest MariaDB version.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's been implemented in 10.2.x (since 10.2.1) which currently is at 10.2.5 RC (release candidate).

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mariadb-1021-release-notes/

Answer (score -1):

MariaDB does not implement subqueries in the `FROM` clause of a view yet because it's based on a version of MySQL that does not implement that feature.

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/ says in part:

> For all practical purposes, MariaDB is a binary drop in replacement **of the same MySQL version** (for example MySQL 5.1 -> MariaDB 5.1, MariaDB 5.2 & MariaDB 5.3 are compatible. MySQL 5.5 is compatible with MariaDB 5.5 and also in practice with MariaDB 10.0).

(emphasis mine)

Not all features of MySQL 5.6, 5.7, or later are implemented in MariaDB. The documentation is pretty clear about the compatibility.

MariaDB is a fork of MySQL 5.5, which was released in 2010. So MariaDB should be backward-compatible and a "drop-in replacement" of that major version of MySQL.

Since then, MySQL has released major versions 5.6 and 5.7, and is currently developing the next version which they have numbered 8.0.

MariaDB has back-ported a few features from MySQL 5.6 and 5.7, but clearly not all features of MySQL 5.6/5.7. It has therefore diverged from compatibility with MySQL, and the differences will get larger as time goes on.

Comment: Anonymous downvoter, care to explain why you think this answer deserves a downvote? Perhaps I can improve it.

Comment: It was not me downvoting your answer, however, I feel that it does not really answer the question and it is not entirely accurate either.

Comment: It is not accurate because apparently MariaDB documentation is not that clear on the compatibility - at least some of the details are incorrect. This is why this question was raised in the first place.

Comment: I don't think it answers the question because it is not specific to the particular issue described in the question. It is too generic.

Comment: Fair enough. I have added a sentence at the beginning of my answer to tie it together.